# video timelapse with timestamp overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, mplayer, timelapse

I'm reconstructing a video from a large amount of jepg files.

I'd like to keep a trace of original images' timestamp (at least every N minutes)
Since there is no *mainstream* video container format allowing per-frame metadata, I could use a text overlay to keep track of the timestamp.

Timestamp is both "stored" in the filename and in the image exif data, and
I would avoid copy/preprocess gigabytes of jpeg with ImageMagick.

Is there a way to combine mencoder `mf://@file-list` with an hypothetical *overlay filter* so that the timestamp of each image is encrusted?
(I'm not even sure that the ffmpeg text filter would fit the need)

Either ffmpeg or mplayer solutions welcomed.

Comment: See method [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/19138/1871). Use `0` for the third value (one after gmtime).